# How to handle the Stainless Steel cable?

Tags: metal, stainless

First, I would like to what is the best tools to cut a Stainless Steel cable?
Second, I would like to know how to install this kind of lock in the stainless stell cable? Thanks.[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This question really isn't on topic here, unless you can somehow connect it to Home Improvement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about Home Improvement.

Comment: Wrap the cable very tightly with tape and cut through the tape.  This will reduce fraying quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Good wire cutters. I have also used a chisel and anvil. Then you need the correct size of crimp or swage fitting. Depending on the size , there are also regular cable clamps. Carbon steel or stainless steel are similar high strength so that makes no difference to the cutting.  I have assumed a small size like 1/8 in.